# Text mask (destination-out) in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

What is the correct way to add text with [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) with a `destination-out` fill mode? I am trying to apply a text mask over a background image.

This is my simple approach so far. I haven't added the BG yet, but would still expect the red mask to be knocked out:

```
<canvas id="logo" width="600" height="250"></canvas>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('logo');
    canvas.backgroundColor="green";
    var mask = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        fill :'red',
    });
    canvas.add(mask);

    var text = new fabric.Text("TEST TEXT", {
        fontSize: 120,
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        fill: 'white',
        stroke: "black",
        fillRule: 'destination-out'
    });
    canvas.add(text);

});
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3x8bs/2/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('logo');
    canvas.backgroundColor="green";
    var mask = new fabric.Rect({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: 600,
        height: 200,
        fill: 'blue'
    });
    canvas.add(mask);

    var text = new fabric.Text("TEST TEXT", {
        fontSize: 120,
        fontFamily: 'Arial',
        stroke: "black",
        fill: 'none',
        fillRule: 'destination-out'
    });
    canvas.add(text);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/3x8bs/3/